# ¿Cómo capturar dos valores de un Select HTML y pasarlo al controlador de AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Tengo un listado de varios selectores (no uno solo) que muestro con Laravel (no es un listado de angular). Al seleccionar una opción, necesito que a la función NG-CHANGE de AngularJS **ingresen dos valores**: un id que estoy usando, llamado $valor->bann_id (hasta aquí me funciona) y también (y aquí viene el problema), que ingrese el valor del option seleccionado, que en mi caso es {{$i}}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito quedaria teoricamente asi:

```
ng-change="guardarOrden( {{$valor->bann_id}}, Valor del option )"
```

En javascript capturabamos el valor del selector con un $this.value o algo similar, pero no se como se hace con angularjs.

Este es mi código:

```
@foreach ($listado as $clave => $valor) //son muchos select

<select  name="bann_orden" ng-model="bann{{$valor->bann_id}}" ng- 
change="guardarOrden({{$valor->bann_id}})">
@for ($i = 1; $i < 500; $i++)
    <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
@endfor
</select>
```

@endforeach

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de encontrar la respuesta en otra pregunta publicada, es con

```
this.bann_orden{{$valor->bann_id}}),
```

donde lo que esta despues del this. corresponde al nombre puesto en el ng-model

Por lo cual el codigo queda, funcionando correctamente, asi:

```
<select name="bann_orden" ng-model="bann_orden{{$valor->bann_id}}" 
ng-change="guardarOrden({{$valor->bann_id}},this.bann_orden{{$valor- 
>bann_id}})">
@for ($i = 1; $i < 500; $i++)
<option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
@endfor
</select>
```